# Magento 1.9 - Custom Options on Product Page - Multiple Columns

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

My apologies if this question is posed elsewhere.

I am utilizing custom options on my product pages and I have about a dozen drop downs per product.  By default, all options list in one column the full width of the block that they are in.  In order to prevent the user from having to scroll down to answer each option, I would like to display them in two or three columns across within the same block.

I am new to Magento and PHP so any help and example would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

As these elements are generated dynamically I would suggest you to use simple CSS and JS to do it. Here is simple bootstrap and jquery solution.

```
var $boxes = jQuery('dl.last').children();
var boxesLen = $boxes.length;
for (var i = 0;i < boxesLen;i+=2){
    $boxes.filter(':eq('+i+'),:eq('+(i+1)+')').wrapAll('<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6"/>');
};
```

Comment: Thank you Mihail.  Can you tell me where I would make these changes?  I'm not sure how to identify the specific files.

Comment: You could apply these in script tag to this file: app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml. Should work properly.

Comment: Thank you again Mihail.  Unfortunately adding this to my view.phtml produced the same results.  Would it be possible to send you the file so you can see it?  Thank you again so much.  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you have bootstrap and jquery libs included in this file?

Comment: I don't.  I'm sorry,  I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Here is a link to the file I am using: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qex05yn4kpd9iqs/view.phtml?dl=0

Comment: Here is updated version. Should work. https://www.dropbox.com/s/866yxy3dz96fdlw/view.phtml?dl=0

Comment: Thanks Mihail!  Almost there.  I get the two columns now but my price doesn't calculate when I make a selection of an option with a price modifier.

Comment: These changes don't affect prices. They just change the layout. Check your custom options.